# What are prefuse data groups and how do I put nodes into them?

Tags: prefuse

Many components of prefuse seem to use a String group to identify some subset of data. How do you use groups in practice? Some documentation seems to imply that a single row of data can belong to multiple groups, but I cannot work out how to make this happen.

Ideally, I could put some nodes of a graph into multiple groups, but have them each visualized once, and apply various forces and layouts to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed most prefuse components such as `Layout`, `ColorAction` or the `RendererFactory` use group names.

There are different types of groups:

- groups created from raw data, e.g. by `vis.addGraph(...)`
- focus groups that contains some items (= rows) from another group
- decorator groups, e.g., for labels
- aggregate groups that represent items merged to aggregated items

In order to put "some nodes of a graph into multiple groups" you can use focus groups. 
Then some `Action` may be added to run only on the focus group.

Alternatively you could pass a `Predicate` to the `Action`, so that only items (= rows) matching the `Predicate` are handled by the `Action`.

I recommend to look at the demos to see how this works: 
for example https://github.com/prefuse/Prefuse/blob/master/demos/prefuse/demos/ZipDecode.java